# WooCommerce - Remove item from cart if specific coupon code or product is not present or removed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon

I have added a function to add a free product when a certain coupon code is entered.

I now need to check if the original product is still in the cart, and if not, remove coupon and free product from the cart.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'apply_product_on_coupon');
function apply_product_on_coupon( ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $coupon_idcus = 'ccam0620';
    $free_product_id = 11259;

    if(in_array($coupon_idcus, $woocommerce->cart->get_applied_coupons())){
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($free_product_id, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need another action to check if the coupon was removed.

```
function action_woocommerce_removed_coupon( $coupon_code ) { 
   if($coupon_code == 'ccam0620') {

     $product_id = 11259;
     $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
     $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
     if ( $cart_item_key ) WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
   }
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_removed_coupon', 'action_woocommerce_removed_coupon', 10, 1 );
```

This should do it - I haven't tested it.

Source 1: http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_removed_coupon/

Source 2: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-remove-product-from-cart-programmatically/

Comment: Glad I could help :)